# How to change all the elements on hover inside a div

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Here's my code:

```
<a class="box" href="http://mylinkhere"><div class="heading-icon"><i class="fa fa-video-camera"></"></i></div>Video Tutorials</a>
```

It's a box with a font icon (font awesome icon) and text. What I want to achieve is when people hover on the box it changes the background colour and text colour including the icon. I was able to change the background colour and text colour "Video Tutorials" on hover but not the icon " fa-video-camera". How can I achieve that?

Appreciate your support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read your question correctly this should work.  Comment if it doesn't.  You wanted the icon color to change when the .box was hovered right?

```
.box:hover .fa-video-camera {
    color: #ccc;
}
```

By the way what is this mysterious symbol `</">` doing between your i tags?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that has worked. I'm learning CSS everyday more:) 
Yes, there's a mysterious symbol there, I'm going to get ride! Many thanks again